# Compile haml, sass & coffeescript on xcode build with PhoneGap

Tags: xcode, coffeescript, xcode4.2, haml, sass

I am using PhoneGap to build an html 5 backed app and I would like to use haml, sass and coffee-script.  Is there a way to build in a hook to the build process in xcode 4.2 so that the files are compiled to HTML, CSS and Javascript?

I am new to xcode and still trying to figure out these complicated build settings.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you're describing is part of whats called the *build phase* (ref docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Building/Building.html)).

After selecting a target in your project you can add a *"Run script"* target that compiles all your custom content types at build time. Since you can specify a "shell" (it's actually any interpreter) you can write it in (almost) whatever language you want.

Some tips:

- There's an environment variable called `$PROJECT_DIR` containing the absolute path to your XCode project. You'll want to use it (e.g. `$PROJECT_DIR/www` points to your `www` folder).
- Put your run script as early in the build phase as possible, since other phases may depend on generated content.
- I strongly advice to have your "Run script" build phase as an executable in your VC, and only use the paste-in script to load the script in your VC.
- [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) is the best (and fastest) way of mirroring another directory without knowing details of it's contents. Especially useful for this task is it's `--delete` flag to prune removed files. If you can run XCode 4.2, it's already present on your system.
- In the end an external watcher script (e.g. [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), `coffee --watch`, `compass --watch`) that outputs their results may be just as effective as a run script build phase.

Comment: Thanks Jacob.  I ended up implementing Guard with a separate src directory.  I found this to be a nice way to keep the files that were most often edited separated from the iOS and html compiled files.

Comment: You're welcome! I've often try the build phase script way, but there always seems to be something that doesn't work quite right, and I go back to watchers injecting sources instead, like you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a [blog post](http://abhishiv.tumblr.com/post/15994872384/phonegap-and-sprockets-sitting-in-a-tree) about this. My recommendation would be to use sprockets with a rack server. Sprockets is the best way to manage assets, and rack server facilitates rapid development through your desktop browser.